# putting a string in a char to an sql statement?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i am using xcode ,and have a question in objective c ,maby you can help me .

my function gets a string, which she takes and put into an sql statement , and i am not sure how to do that because the statement is a char, and i found many ways to convert it.

i do this :

```
sql_for_event= " SELECT basic_pic,spriteSheet,sound FROM DataBase WHEN event= %c",[awaking_event UTF8String] ;
```

when sql_for_event is the statement, and awaking_event is a NSString i get to  the function.
how can i do that ?

thanks a lot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The %c specifier only prints a single `char` and it would need to be a part of an `sprintf` call with your scenario. An easier way would be

```
sql_for_event= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT basic_pic,spriteSheet,sound FROM DataBase WHERE event= '%@'",awaking_event] UTF8String];
```

Comment: i did what you said but i get warnning :  warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type .... ?

Comment: sql_for_event needs to be declared as `const char *`

Comment: Although I showed you how to get the char * from the NSString also consider aknew's answer about binding.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not entirely correct. Try something like:

```
char buffer[2048];
sprintf(buffer,
    "SELECT basic_pic,spriteSheet,sound FROM DataBase WHEN event='%s'",
    [awaking_event UTF8String]
);
```

Your approach lacked of:

1. Proper memory allocation (you can't just assign a string constant to a `char*` and then modify it.
2. Your SQL probably needs `''` if you are dealing with character fields.
3. With `%c` you only get a byte (character) of data, not a character array.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use sqlite API sqlite3_bind_text:

```
sql_for_event= " SELECT basic_pic,spriteSheet,sound FROM DataBase WHEN event= ?";
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {       
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [awaking_event UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    //next actions with statement - sqlite3_step(statement) etc
}
```